# ¿Cómo puedo Ejecutar código Js dependiendo en la página que estoy?

Tags: ajax, laravel, permisos

He estado metiendo mi código Js con Vue y extrayendo mi información con Axios.  Digamos que en vista llamada productos tengo un `div` con su `Id` misproductos

```html
<div id="misproductos">
     Aqui Cargo la lista de mis productos ..
</div>
```

para que posteriormente con Axios extraiga mis lista de productos. Hasta ahí todo esta bien.

```html
new Vue({
    el:'#misproductos',
    created:function(){
      this.getProductos();
    },
    data:{
      lista:[],
      errors:[]
    },
    methods:{
      getPerfil:function(){
        var url = 'productos';
        axios.get(url).then(response=>{
          this.lista = response.data
        });
      }
    }
 });
```

todo perfecto, pero mi problema es que todo este código Js lo estoy metiendo en uno solo dónde al ejecutar el comando

```
npm run dev
```

todo se junta un mismo archivo llamado App.js perfecto, sí. Pero ahora el problema viene cuando yo quiero cambiar de vista (Ej. a mi vista Home) me sale un error en Chrome al inspeccionar elemento

> app.js:30755 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #misproductos

podría hacer que todo fuera llamando a mis métodos y extraer la información 
pero no, yo quiero lograr que cuando se visite la vista productos se muestre la lista de productos automáticamente o ¿cuál sería una mejor práctica?

Comment: Entiendo que estas utilizando laravel mix. Si es así,  mi recomendación es que lo configures para que los archivos js con código específico de una vista no los incluya en el App.js en su lugar mejor que te genere otro archivo.js con el código js especifico de esa vista que luego deberás incluir con asset en dicha vista. Esto evita que que trasfieras código innecesario a todas las vistas y por tanto que se ejecute con errores.

Comment: entonces así es como lo dejaré, pensé que había alguna u otra forma más elegante. Ya lo he hecho tal y como me dijo, ahora funciona bien ya todo.